# Installation of python-weka-wrapper3 failing on Windows 11 using pip, within a virtual environment using the PS in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, pip

**Device:**
Running Windows 11, in a Virtual environment

**What and when:**

When installing python-weka-wrapper3 I get the error on installing javabridge

```
 Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\rokma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k1w_wc1a\python-javabridge_aa9e4024f3b64514a623f6067161d163\setup.py", line 412, in <module>
          ext_modules=ext_modules(),
        File "C:\Users\rokma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k1w_wc1a\python-javabridge_aa9e4024f3b64514a623f6067161d163\setup.py", line 120, in ext_modules
          p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

**Steps tried:**

- I have tried reinstalling JDK and pointing JAVA_HOME to jdk 8, 11 and 19
- using

```
set MSSdk=1
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
pip install javabridge
```

- repairing Visual C++ above the version of 14.0
- other steps that I've forgotten to list

Comment: Have you tried installing the pre-compiled binaries for numpy and javabridge as [per instructions](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/install.html#windows)? That should avoid having to compile anything.

Comment: I've failed to mention it's in a virtual environment. I'll edit that right now in the main post.

Comment: Thanks, your link of the installation worked!